# Want to make a batch to create a table of weekly ranking on Magento

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I'd like to marge those two arrays like that below. And it's taking so long... Can you please help me out?

```
result=
array {
  [0]=>
  array{
    ["product_id"]=>"418"
    ["qty_ordered"]=>"2.0000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array{
    ["product_id"]=>"512"
    ["qty_ordered"]=>"3.0000"
  }
  [2]=>
  array{
    ["product_id"]=>"588"
    ["qty_ordered"]=>"1.0000"
  }
}

result1=
array {
  [0]=>
  array {
    ["id"]=>"2"
    ["period"]=>"2015-12-08"
    ["store_id"]=>"0"
    ["product_id"]=>"418"
    ["rating_pos"]=>"0"
    ["out_of_stock"]=>"1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array {
    ["id"]=>"4"
    ["period"]=>"2015-11-08"
    ["store_id"]=>"0"
    ["product_id"]=>"588"
    ["rating_pos"]=>"0"
    ["out_of_stock"]=>"0"
  }
}
```

those arrays to like this (adding "out_of_stock" from bottom one to top one) There are many arrays to marge, so I want to make a foreach statement butI've been stuck for so long....

The common key is "product_id", and the "out_of_stock will be 0 if the common product_id doesn't exist in $result1

```
result2=
array {
  [0]=>
  array{
    ["product_id"]=>"418"
    ["qty_ordered"]=>"2.0000"
    ["out_of_stock"]=>"1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array{
    ["product_id"]=>"512"
    ["qty_ordered"]=>"3.0000"
    ["out_of_stock"]=>"0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array{
    ["product_id"]=>"588"
    ["qty_ordered"]=>"1.0000"
    ["out_of_stock"]=>"0"
  }
}
```

I've created up to here like this, but I'm sure it'll be so long and not good at all...

```
$rowArray=array();
        foreach($result as $rowArray){
            foreach ($rowArray as $column => $value) {
                if($colum = 'product_id'){
                .....
```

I really appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key is fixed,So you don't need loop $rowArray

```
foreach($result as &$val1){
    $val1['out_of_stock'] = 0;//make it to be 0 as default
    foreach($result1 as $val2){
        if($val1['product_id'] == $val2['product_id']){
            $val1['out_of_stock'] = $val2['out_of_stock'];
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$result = array_reduce($result, function ($return, $item) {
    $return[$item['product_id']] = $item;
    return $return;
}, array());

$result1 = array_reduce($result1, function ($return, $item) {
    $return[$item['product_id']] = $item;
    return $return;
}, array());

$result = array_replace_recursive($result, $result1);

$result = array_map(function($item) {
    $item['out_of_stock'] = isset($item['out_of_stock']) ? $item['out_of_stock'] : 0;
    return $item;
}, $result);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```